# Get file URL of a FS.File object with Meteor

Tags: url, collections, meteor, meteorite

I'm using Meteor's CollectionFS and trying to display image files that were uploaded to the server. The I've attached a reference to the file objects in another object, as such:

```
  Entries.insert({
    title: title,
    caption: caption,
    file: fsFile,
  });
```

I call `Entries.find({})` and return that to a template, which I use to iterate through the entries. I've tried `<img src="file.url">`, but that doesn't work.

It works fine if I call the images collection directly, `Images.find({})`, and iterate through the files, getting their urls with the file context `this.url`. Is there a similar way to do it using the references in the Entires objects?

Comment: Check this part of the documentation: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#storing-fsfile-references-in-your-objects  fsFile is just a reference to a file. If you want to get the data of the image you have to use the file.getFileRecord() method.  This just works if the image was subscribed. If you dont use insecure/autopublish you have to do some joins on your own.

Comment: That's right. You need to do some joins but `getFileRecord()` does not give much info. Try putting `FS.debug=true` where you're handling the submit event. On browser console you can see the link it creates that probably goes `/cfs/files/<collectionName>/<fileObj.id>`

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this: (**note I'm using the underscore package**)

```
Template.image_queue.helpers({
    images: function() {
        return _.map(Images.find().fetch(), function(image) {
            return image.url();
        });
    }
});
```

Asuming

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {
        path: "~/uploads"
    })]
});

Images.allow({
    insert: function (userId, party) {
        return true;
    },
    update: function (userId, party) {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function (userId, party) {
        return true;
    },
    download: function (userId, party) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!

Comment: works good and it is the best solution I found to this and really miss it in the docs as the normal {{this.url}} solution is not flexible at all especially when referencing images by another collection. The only downside I found was the handler gets called two times for each image. I used it like this: `var result = _.map(welcomeImages.find({"_id": imageId}).fetch(), function(image) {
            return image.url();
        });` while looping through the main collection where `imageId` is the reference to the according image.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't published and subscribed to your CFS file, file.url returns undefined. In this case you can get file url by following way:

```
/cfs/files/{cfs_collection_name}/{fs_file_id}
```

For example:

```
<img src="/cfs/files/images/{{ file._id }}">
```